# DISCORDPY Command raised an exception: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string instance, Context found

Tags: python

Expected Output: Send output of the DB query in a message
Output: No message
Error in console: Command raised an exception: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string instance, Context found
DiscordPY version: 1.3.3 (rewrite ofc) with cogs
Code:

```
@commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def mysqlrcon(self, ctx):
        cursor = db.cursor()
        command = ctx.args[1:]
        command = " ".join(command)
        cursor.execute(command)
        ctx.send(cursor.fetchall())
```

Tried converting it to byte, expected byte like instance. Tried my best. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, for anyone interested:

```
@commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def mysqlrcon(self, ctx, *, message):
        cursor = db.cursor()
        
        args = ctx.message.content.split(" ")  # split by spaces
        command = args[1:]  # get everything except the bot command itself
        command = " ".join(command)  # join mysql command together
        cursor.execute(command)
        await ctx.send(cursor.fetchall())
```